# jsps give me a bunch of errors, probably due to DOCTYPE

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

First here:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

I get the warning: "`Undefined attribute name (xmlns).`" What's the best way to solve this in Eclipse?

I also get an error here "Missing quotes for attribute value (it refers to center)

```
<table align=center>

<%  if(action!=null && "sendemail".equals(action)){
         if(!"".equals(error)){%><tr><td colspan=2 align=center>
            <span class="redtext"><%=error%></span></td></tr> <%
         }
    }
%>
```

two questions: how do I fix this and where do I set DOCTYPE?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding some quotes since it tells you they're missing from align and colspan, e.g. colspan="2" align="center"

Comment: Check out this previous post also... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541335/editing-xhtml-jsp-files-in-eclipse

Comment: It's seems to have worked before, maybe I using a newer version? I thought center was a keyword and didn't require quotes.

Comment: XML (and, thus, XHTML) required quotes around every attribute value. Can you include your page header in your question?

Comment: I should be able to, allegedly it used work before :(

Comment: Do you only get errors in the editor, but the page looks fine when you point your webbrowser to it?

Comment: page gives an error, saying that path is not found...

Answer (score 1):

Which Eclipse editor type are you using to view the file? Judging by those error messages, you're using the XML editor, which won't get you far, since that sort of JSP isn't an XML file.

If you're using the Java EE version of Eclipse, then open the JSP with the JSP editor. If you're using the standard Java version, then go and download the Java EE version :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the xmlns attribute unless your file's DOCTYPE indicates that it's XHTML and not plain HTML.